# Окно в c++

Tags: c++

Вопрос наверно очень тупой )) но все же не могу в программе изменить размер окна, то есть форми. Ввожу например в коде какой то кнопки 
    Form1->Width=300 (либо Form1->Height=300) 
и вискакивает ошибка, типа виражение слева долно указивать на класс. Помогите пожалуйста.
Работаю в Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю Form1 это класс, а не экземляр? Если Вы изменяете размеры, например, в обработчике клика кнопки пренадлежащей этой формы, тогда так:

```
this->Width = 300;
```

Если же Вы хотите изменить размеры формы №1 из формы №2, то в форму №2 надо передать ссылку на форму №1.